# Fixing A* implementation in C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, a-star

So I've implemented an A* algorithm in Unity C# to do some tests in order to build a 2D based game. I know there are several components out there that help you with this but I want to try myself just for the challenge.

I have basically read how the A* should behave and translated the behaviour into code. It almost works. But there are some ocassions where the adjacent tiles have exactly the same score (manhattan distance + distance from origin) and you end up with a path that leads to the destination but is not the shortest. As you can see in the image, those two adjacent tiles have the same score, but I pick up a random one at that point...(In the image below, the starting point is the cat and the red cross is the destination point. The green semi-transparent files is the calculated path)

[image]

I was thinking that since there are not too many tiles, I could calculate the 4 different paths from the 4 initial adjacent tiles, store the valid ones in a array, and then basically just use the shortest, but maybe that will be too much overhead and there is another solution?

To calculate the distance I'm using a basic calculation:

```
private int CalculateManhattanDistance(int x1, int x2, int y1, int y2)
{
        return Mathf.Abs(x1 - x2) + Mathf.Abs(y1 - y2);
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm struggling to understand your problem. A* is by its nature guaranteed to find the optimal path (where optimality is guided by your heuristic function). There may be multiple equally optimal paths and some of them you might like more than others but mathematically they are all equivalent with respect to your heuristic/scoring function. Perhaps your A* implementation is incorrect?

Comment: What I mean is that the final path selected might lead to the destination, but is not the shortest and maybe there is a way to optimize this? The path selected in the image is not the shortest path to the destination.

Comment: If the image in your post has the meaning of: "animal face" = start point, "red cross" = goal and "tiles marked green" = path (it would help if that was written in your post), then that path is really not optimal. My guess would be that you are not storing the list of not visited nodes and only consider the ones that are adjacent to the node you have just expanded. A* always expands the node with lowest score next, regardless of it's relation to the latest expanded node. It is hard to tell without seeing your code where the problem is.

Comment: Yes, you are right I've updated the post, thanks for the suggestions. I don't really understand what you mean by storing the visited tiles. Are you saying that I should do several attempts for the calculation and store them somewhere? Right now I only check once for the lowest score of the adjacent tile and pick the first one that comes along. Is that wrong?

Comment: Yes, that is wrong, you always need to choose the node/tile with lowest overall score as the next to visit. Check some A* illustrating animations to see how this guides the node expansion towards the goal even through multiple optimal paths or when there's an obstacle. There's some very nice images with the scores as gradients/colors in http://theory.stanford.edu/~amitp/GameProgramming/AStarComparison.html Notice how the Greedy Best-first algorithm does something similar to yours.

Comment: I first store all the adjacent tiles from where I'm doing the calculation. Each one has it's score calculated just before I store them. But there are some points where the score is the same (like in the image above), they both have 8. Which do I choose? Because from what I see that is the problem that is leading to longer paths.

Comment: If you have two nodes `a` and `b` with equal score `s`, choose however you like. If you expanded neighbors of `a` and all of them led to sub-optimal paths (e.g. due to an obstacle), all of the `a`'s neighbors will have a score higher than `s` which will cause the node `b` to be the one to be expanded next. The point is that you need to expand the lowest score node of all. If there are multiple of those, the order among them is arbitrary.

Comment: After reading through your replies, I think I finally understood-> "A* always expands the node with lowest score next, regardless of it's relation to the latest expanded node.". So I need to constantly keep track of the score, the next node's score should always be lower or equals than the previous one right? If not, I need to calculate another path. correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this help you to understand what both @Zdeněk Jelínek and @Peter Wishart have pointed out. The openSet (also named frontier), usually is a [PriorityQueue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue). The nodes of the queue are sorted according to their priorities. The priority of a node is calculated as the sum of the cost so far (number of steps in your case) and the heuristic distance (Manhattan in your case). Therefore, as soon A* reaches the node with priority 11, it will stop to explore that path and will continue with the others (blue circle)

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I think I finally understood. But, once you reach that 11. How do you know what node to pick next? The next node with lowest score closer to the start?

Comment: @Bastrix As you progress with the algorithm execution, you always put the expanded node neighbors and their scores into the `openSet`, even though you do not visit them. And so once there is an 11, you'll see that in the `openSet` is something with lower score and choose that as the next one.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend checking the pseudocode for **A*** [e.g. on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm#Pseudocode) against your code.

Based on that pseudocode you would implement the algorithm data like this, I suspect you have simplified some of these:

```
        var closedSet = new HashSet<GraphNode>();
        var openSet = new List<GraphNode>{startNode};
        var cameFrom = new Dictionary<GraphNode, GraphNode>();
        var gScore = new Dictionary<GraphNode, double>();
        var fScore = new Dictionary<GraphNode, double>();
```

When the algorithm makes a bad first choice for the heuristic, as in this test case, it will initially evaluate a move in the wrong direction.
But this isn't a problem as it should:

- Select an open node with the lowest `fScore`
- Evaluate all reachable neighbours (e.g. including the node to the *left* of the start node in your example's 1st iteration)
- Update `gScore` with actual distance (via cameFrom)
- Update `fScore` with actual distance plus estimated (e.g. Manhattan) distance to target
- Move evaluated nodes from `openSet` to `closedSet`

This means that nodes along the "wrong" path will compute increasing actual + expected distances, to the extent that the algorithm starts choosing other `open` nodes e.g. the "right" node from the 1st iteration.